# Как валидировать на равенство одному из значений?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Нужно, чтобы валидация проходила, только если поле равно 1 или 25. Пробовал это:

```
validates :x, numericality: { equal_to: (1 || 25) }
```

...но это не работает.

Comment: Я полностью перелопатил вопрос, проверьте, соответствует ли он тому, что вы спрашивали. В особенности, похож ли пример на то, что вы пробовали.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Знаете, чему равно `(1 || 25)`? А проверьте в IRB:

```
(1 || 25) # => 1
```

**Вот это поворот!** Но почему?

Потому что `||` выдаёт первый (слева) операнд, который не `nil` и не `false`. Это ["накоротко-замкнутое ИЛИ"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), которое **всегда возвращает один из своих операндов** (независимо от их типов! это может сломать мозг в отдельных случаях):

- Вычисляется левый, если он не `false` и не `nil`, он и возвращается
- ...иначе вычисляется и возвращается правый (каким бы он ни был)

И если присмотреться, то для булевых операндов (только `true` и `false`) это всё ещё обычное "или", оно действует в условиях ожидаемым образом. Но для других типов этот оператор приобретает совсем другой смысл.

```
false || nil   # => nil
1     || nil   # => 1
nil   || false # => false
"wat" || nil   # => "wat"
0     || "wat" # => "wat"  -- 0 ведёт себя как true!
```

Ещё один интересный спецэффект: когда операндами являются не значения, а выражения, которые значения возвращают. Если после вычисления левого операнда результат уже известен, то правый операнд не будет даже вычисляться.

```
true || puts('Это не выведется!')
```

Это я всё к чему.

**...фактически** у вас получилась валидация на равенство `1`. **Упс.**

---

Здесь нужна скорее [валидация на `inclusion`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_inclusion_of), принадлежность набору значений:

```
validates :x, inclusion: { in: [1, 25] }
```